# Получение координат мышки в ICommand

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

На данный момент для получения координат мышки использую вот такой подход:

**XAML**

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewDragOver">
            <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="UIElement_OnPreviewDragOver" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
</interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**VM**

```
public void UIElement_OnPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point = e.GetPosition((TreeView)sender);
}
```

Не устраивает то что я внутри `VM` работаю с контролом, и хотелось бы переделать этот обработчик на `ICommand`. Но как тогда получать координаты мышки?

Comment: win32 методы не хочешь юзать?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, Да мне кажется что в этой ситуации можно и без `WinApi` обойтись.

Comment: Ну по идее нужен кастомная реализация EventToCommand, которая пробросит в командпараметер Point точки

Comment: Точнее, нужен кастомный наследник класса [`TriggerAction<ICommand>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726548(v=expression.40).aspx)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Не совсем понимаю как мне здесь использовать `TriggerAction<ICommand>`

Comment: А зачем вам в VM координаты мыши?

Comment: @VladD, Сложно обьяснить вообще всю идею, т.к. модель для приложения пишу не я. Если вкратце, то модель принимает координаты мышки при драг-н-дропе и отвечает в каком месте упадет обьект если отпустить кнопку.

Comment: @Lightness: Очень странно, не модельное это дело — вообще знать о существовании UI и о том, что в системе есть мышка. Ну раз хотят костыль, то и давайте им костыль. Я бы тогда сделал метод в code behind вашего UI, который подписал бы на `PreviewDragOver`, а этот метод пусть уж выясняет координаты мыши и дёргает команду.

Comment: @VladD, А как из `code behind` передавать параметры мыши в команду?

Comment: @Lightness: Ну например упакуйте в структуру, и запихните её в `parameter`.

Comment: @VladD, Так и сделал, все сработало, спасибо.

Comment: @Lightness: Тогда напишу в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку координаты мыши не так просто подключить через XAML, проще всего сделать обёртку в code-behind. Пусть ваша команда в VM лежит в свойстве `DragCommand`.

В XAML:

```
<Grid PreviewDragOver="OnPreviewDragOver" ...>
```

В code-behind нужно сделать вот что:

Кладём dependency property, чтобы не кастить `DataContext` к типу `VM`.

```
public ICommand DragPreviewCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DragPreviewCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DragPreviewCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty DragPreviewCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DragPreviewCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyWindow));
```

В конструкторе устанавливаем привязку (в XAML не получится):

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBinding(DragPreviewCommandProperty, "DragCommand");
}
```

И определяем обработчик:

```
void OnPreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var senderUIElement = (UIElement)sender;
    var mousePosition = e.GetPosition(senderUIElement);
    var command = DragPreviewCommand;
    if (command != null)
        command.Execute(mousePosition);
}
```